# chef setting (default) attributes when using knife node from file

Tags: json, attributes, chef-infra, knife

I'm using a JSON file to configure a (already bootstrapped) node, and trying to identify the right syntax to set node specific attributes. Here is the JSON file used:

```
{
  "name": "mynode",
  "run_list": [
    "snmp"
  ],
  "default_attributes": {
    "server_url": "http://mynode/",
    "interval": "20"
  },
  "normal": {
    "tags": [

    ]
  }
}
```

Commands (note attributes not showing in last command results):

```
>knife --version
Chef: 12.9.41
>knife node from file .\mynode.json
Updated Node mynode
>knife node show mynode
Node Name:   mynode
Environment: _default
FQDN:
IP:
Run List:    recipe[snmp]
Roles:
Recipes:
Platform:
Tags:
```

What would be the right syntax to set default/normal/overridden attributes on the node?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35433711/304690

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19021289/304690

Comment: Don't do this. Derive your attributes from cookbooks and eventually roles resp. environments. Also, don't use `override`, you usually don't need it. The [environment cookbook pattern](http://blog.vialstudios.com/the-environment-cookbook-pattern/) gives you a good impression of how many people think a good workflow looks like (at least I hope it helps you understanding why your approach is bad).

Comment: I'm specifically not using roles, as they are not versioned. Thank you for the pointer, I will study the cookbook patterns to learn more.

Comment: Okay, that's good. But how is what you are doing versioned?

Comment: The cookbooks are, while the attributes aren't versioned.

Comment: Sure, but you're not setting the attributes in cookbook. But we're getting OT..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set default/override attributes in a node, only normal. The syntax for `knife node from file` is what you have there (minus the `default_attributes` which does nothing).

Comment: What is the right way to see if attributes got set?